# Combination matrices with conditions and weighted data in R

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, weighted

Lets say I have 5 diseases (a,b,c,d,e). Each person in the sample was asked if they have each of the diseases and then were assigned a weight (W). I need to determine the proportion of each disease combination in the population. This would involve combinations where people answer (1,1) for either disease combination.

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 0, 0),
  b = c(1, 1, 0, NA),
  c = c(0, 1, NA, 1),
  d = c(1, 1, 0, 1  ),
  e = c(1, 1, 1, 0  ),
  W = c(1.5,3.5,2.5,2.3))

df
  a  b  c d e   W
1 1  1  0 1 1 1.5
2 1  1  1 1 1 3.5
3 0  0 NA 0 1 2.5
4 0 NA  1 1 0 2.3
```

I have been able to figure this out to get a matrix:

```
DisDyads <- apply (df, 2, function (x) colSums (df == 1 & x == df, na.rm = TRUE))

  a b c d e W
a 2 2 1 2 2 0
b 2 2 1 2 2 0
c 1 1 2 2 1 0
d 2 2 2 3 2 0
e 2 2 1 2 3 0
W 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I turn these into proportions instead?

This is an example of what the 1st and 2nd row of the matrix output would look like with proper conditions and as proportions:

```
   a    b    c     d    e    W
a  0.5  0.5  0.25  0.5  0.5  0
b  0.5  0.5  0.25  0.5  0.5  0
```

Next, I also need to account for the weights while determining the proportion of each combination at the population level.

Can someone please help me figure this out? What if I was trying to look for the proportion of three disease combinations? Example. the proportion of people which has a,b,c and a,b,d and so on..

I really appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the algorithm to calculate these proportions (and weights)?

Comment: It's just a simple multiply each person by their weight and then divide by (nrow(df)*sum(df$W) @RomanLuštrik

Comment: You may need to analyze this a different way, and/or view your data differently. Your data aren't independent, so you can't treat them as such. You are counting occurrences of each disease separately, which you shouldn't, you have no occurrence of just one disease. Come up with your combinations (to keep it short I just show a, b and c): `a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc`. Then your responses for each patient: `1, 2, 3, 4`. You can't portray this in a combination matrix, which show pairwise combinations.

Comment: I am not counting occurrences of each disease on its own in this case. a and a being present together together in the matrix just means that's the proportion of having that disease, even if you might have another disease. It's very inefficient to do the combinations one by one. This is just an example... my actual data set has a lot more diseases. @Anonymouscoward

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I see now. You want to essentially make a cross-tab lookup table. That's not going to be easy to display. It'll be big, since you'll need to display all combinations, and have lots of duplication.

As far making them proportions, you'll just divide your whole data frame (except col W) by nrow, then multiply rows by proportional weights (W/sum(W)):

```
df[,1:5] <- df[,1:5]/nrow(df)
```

To multiply your weights, it'll take some manipulating.

```
df <- as.matrix(df)
df <- as.data.frame(t(t(df[,1:5]*(df[,6] / sum(df[,6]))))) # this subsets your data, and multiplies each cell in cols 1:5 by the proportional weights.


       a          b          c          d          e
1 0.03826531 0.03826531 0.00000000 0.03826531 0.03826531
2 0.08928571 0.08928571 0.08928571 0.08928571 0.08928571
3 0.00000000 0.00000000         NA 0.00000000 0.06377551
4 0.00000000         NA 0.05867347 0.05867347 0.00000000
```

I'd think you could just get your weighted values, then go from there. Shouldn't the combinations just be additive?

Comment: I have been able to use the following to get weighted proportion of each combination of disease:

                                   Dyads <- apply (df, 2, function (x) colSums (((df == 1 & x == df)* df$W), na.rm = TRUE))

Dyads_w <- Dyads/sum(data4$Weights)*100

Now, I am trying to figure out how to determine proportion of three disease combinations. I understand I can't use the same methodology that I used for two disease combinations. Any ideas on how to approach this? I really appreciate the help :)